# Curl Command in Python 3 on Pi with User Name and Password

Tags: curl

Hope someone can help with this syntax error from this curl statement in python 3 running on a pi. I am using the following general format to pass a variable to a home automation controller

curl -u USER:PASSWORD http://192.xxx.x.xx/rest/vars/set/1/3/16

This is the error I get.  For security purposes, I have not shown my address  in the following statement from which I get the syntax error.

My username is admin and my password is test

```
curl-u admin:test http://192.xxx.x.xx/rest/vars/set/2/77/16
           ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `curl -u ...` missing space?

Comment: If that's the Python error (that's what it looks like) you need to show us your Python code.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely on-topic for Raspberry Pi, but...

This question was asked in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594880/using-curl-with-a-username-and-password), but it's rather old now. Some opined that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27894407/5395338) was better than the "accepted" answer. You have used the "accepted answer"; the alternative might be worth a try. Take a look at some of the other answers - you may find other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to close this question.  I found out today that you cannot use curl in a python program on the Pi.  Instead I used "request".

I am using a rest command to push a variable in my server.

This is the replacement statement I used along with the full test program for anyone who may have the same issue.

requests.get('http://192.xxx.x.xx/rest/vars/set/2/19/45', auth=('User', 'PW'))

`
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_BMP.BMP085 as BMP085
import I2C_LCD_driver
import time
import pycurl
import requests

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

pressure_sensor = BMP085.BMP085()
sensor = BMP085.BMP085()

mylcd = I2C_LCD_driver.lcd()
mylcd.lcd_clear()
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()

pressure = pressure_sensor.read_sealevel_pressure()
pressure = pressure / 100.0 # 1 mbar = 100 Pa.

if pressure > 700:
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("Pressure: %.1f%s hPa" % (pressure,chr(32)), 3)
        requests.get('http://192.xxx.x.xx/rest/vars/set/2/19/45', auth=('User', 'PW'))
time.sleep(20)
`